# Add a Woocommerce cart fee does not persist in checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

I use add_fee method to charge my cart price. It works and it is OK but when I click the checkout button and I go to the checkout page or I refresh the page the new price disappear and old price is there . How can I save my price in cart?

```
function woo_add_cart_fee($cart_obj) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $count = $_POST['qa'];

    $extra_shipping_cost = 0;
    //Loop through the cart to find out the extra costs
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        //Get the product info
        $_product = $values['data'];

        //Adding together the extra costs
        $extra_shipping_cost = $extra_shipping_cost + $_product->price;
    }

    $extra_shipping_cost = $extra_shipping_cost * $count;
    //Lets check if we actually have a fee, then add it
        if ($extra_shipping_cost) {
            $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('count', 'woocommerce'),   $extra_shipping_cost );
        }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'woo_add_cart_fee');
```

Comment: Could you put your code with which you use add_fee here, so that we could have a look and see if you have overlook or missed anything out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` hook instead. I have also revisited your code as you should need to store the `$_POST['qa'];` value to make the fee persistent:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'cart_custom_fee', 20, 1 );
function cart_custom_fee( $cart_obj ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    $count = $_POST['qa'];

    $extra_shipping_cost = 0;

    // Loop through the cart items to find out the extra costs
    foreach ( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        //Adding together the extra costs
        $extra_shipping_cost = $extra_shipping_cost + $cart_item['data']->price;
    }

    $extra_shipping_cost = $extra_shipping_cost * $count;

    //Lets check if we actually have a fee, then add it
    if ( $extra_shipping_cost != 0 ) {
        $cart_obj->add_fee( __('count', 'woocommerce'),   $extra_shipping_cost );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

This should work as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is coming across this wondering why the fee is showing on the checkout page but not on the thank you page or in the order...the reason it was happening to me was that I was making use of `$_POST['post_data']` on the checkout page to get the form fields.

`woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` runs a few times after clicking the Place Order button and the `$_POST['post_data']` would be empty at that point so the fee would not get attached to the order.

The solution is to store the fee you want to use into the customer session and then use some smart logic to set the fee at approapriate times:

```
function setAdditionalFee() {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! is_checkout() ) { // Remove this block if you want fee to show on cart
        return;
    }

    $fee_label = __( 'Additional Charge', 'text-domain' );

    $posted_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['post_data'] ?? '' );

    /**
     * Bail for new orders.
     */
    if ( empty( $posted_data ) && empty( WC()->session->get( 'my_custom_fee' ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    /**
     * This check happens when customer clicks "Place Order" button and ajax runs.
     * $posted_data would be empty but we would have already set the session key for the fee on the checkout page.
     */
    if ( empty( $posted_data ) && ! empty( WC()->session->get( 'my_custom_fee' ) ) ) {
        WC()->cart->add_fee( $fee_label, WC()->session->get( 'my_custom_fee' ) );
        WC()->session->set( 'my_custom_fee', false ); // Set to false so new orders don't show the fee until it is set.
        return;
    }

    $fee        = 2.00; // set your custom fee dynamically here

    if ( empty( $fee ) ) {
        WC()->session->set( 'my_custom_fee', false );
        return;
    }

    WC()->session->set( 'my_custom_fee', $fee );

    /**
     * This fee is shown on the checkout page but the actual attaching happens after the Place Order button is clicked
     * And the fee is retrieved from the session and added.
     * This can be seen in the if ( empty( $posted_data ) && ! empty( WC()->session->get( 'my_custom_fee' ) ) ){} logic above.
     */
    WC()->cart->add_fee( $fee_label, $fee );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'setAdditionalFee', 100 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [UriahsVictor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77656386/15197984), I had the same issue with `$_POST['post_data']` accessing. Only want to suggest the different approach - we can save the post data in cookies and leave the only one logic instead of creating complicated logic, something like this:

```
function setAdditionalFee() {

  if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
    return;
  }

  if ( ! is_checkout() ) { // Remove this block if you want fee to show on cart
    return;
  }

  // Save the post data to cookies with session expiration (0) 
  if ( ! empty( $_POST['post_data'] ) ) {
    setcookie( 'customer-post-data', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['post_data'] ), 0 );
 }

  $fee_label = __( 'Additional Charge', 'text-domain' );

  $posted_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['post_data'] ?? '' );

  // in case of absence of $_POST['post_data'] - take it from cookie
  if ( empty( $posted_data ) && ! empty( $_COOKIE['customer-post-data'] ) ) {
    $posted_data = $_COOKIE['customer-post-data'];
  }

  // below - simple logic like if we do have the $_POST['post_data']
  // ...
}
```